# What is the purpose of Attack Chroma?

Tags: overlight

**What are the benefits of Chroma that deal damage?**

There are a small handful of Chroma that can deal damage to enemies, such as *Mindstrike* or *Greenbane* (only against Banyari).  However, these all seem to do equal or less damage than using regular attacks, while also having added costs and/or risks associated with them (as well as requiring being a Skyborn in the first place, which all PCs are, but is implied to be special and powerful).

A normal attack deals 1 damage per success, allowing up to 6 damage.  Other than using your turn in combat, there is no additional cost.  Comparatively, *Mindstrike* deals 2 damage for 2 successes, 3 damage for 4 successes, or 6 damage for 6 successes (slightly less).  *Mindstrike* also requires passing an additional check in the form of an Open Test against the foe, lest the damage be completely negated.  Furthermore, all Chroma require spending 1 to 4 valuable Spirit points in order to cast, with the additional risk (albeit an avoidable one) of Shattering.

*Greenbane,* when used as a combat spell, is similar.  It deals equal damage to a normal attack (1 damage per 1 success), but only against Banyari, costs Spirit Points, and can Shatter.  The description notes that this is considered a heinous war crime, despite its lack of added effectiveness compared to other forms of murder.

Why would I go through the effort of all these extra steps, costs, and risks to channel these Chroma when I could just hit someone with my sword (or axe, knife, fists, etc)?  **Are there any additional benefits to using Chroma in combat?**